# ClassCastException with inner join (HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, hql

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting a ClassCastException, please? And how to solve it.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();    
        Query query = session.createQuery("from InvestigationMaterial as im inner join im.orderEntry as e");
        List<?> list =query.list();
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            Object[] row = (Object[]) list.get(i);
            OrderEntry oe = (OrderEntry)row[0];
            InvestigationMaterial im = (InvestigationMaterial)row[1];
            System.out.println( "oe= " + oe.getFirstname() + "im = " + im.getType());
 }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   forensikmysql.entity.InvestigationMaterial cannot be cast to
>   forensikmysql.entity.OrderEntry   at
>   forensikmysql.Util.Dao.main(Dao.java:43)

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280818/java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-entity-usere)

Comment: It tells you that, at the second line from below in the code you provided, you cannot cast InvestigationMaterial to OrderEntry(row[1])

Comment: Thanks, I saw the link, but it didn't help me

Comment: Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that your for loop is correct, because no matter how long your list is you will always just use the first two of them. What if your result is just one row? You need to rethink your code there.

Comment: Have you tried to debbug the code? Obviously `InvestigationMaterial` is really in `row[0]`. If you want to avoid the Exception you could do a check if `row[0]` is instance of `OrderEntry`. Other than that you can not just cast one class to an other.  Your class `OrderEntry` needs to be a subclass of `InvestigationMaterial` in order so that you can cast it.

Comment: Thank you, kaba713!

Comment: kaba713, if you can show me how I retrieve the query in a jtable, you would be my hero. :-)

Comment: I'm not good with JTable but you should show us more of your code. Provide the code of `InvestigationMaterial` and `OrderEntry`, and ideally also show us how your database looks like. The more code you provide the easier it is for others to understand your problem and help you.