# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to entityClass

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am getting values using JPA query and putting the result in a List but in service class when I try to convert Entity to DTO.. I am getting the error "Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to entityClass" 
...I have tried forloop, forEach loop and iterator getting error. The moment i try to fetch the first element and put it into the entityclass object i get this error.

```
List<Dashboard> dashboard = (List<Dashboard>)dashboardRepository.findAll();

    System.out.println("AllSolCount Length :------------------------------- "+dashboard.size());
    List<DashboardDto> result = new ArrayList<DashboardDto>();
    System.out.println("List Elements :----------------------------------- "+dashboard);
    /*for(int i=0;i<dashboard.size();i++) {
        **Dashboard obj = (Dashboard)dashboard.get(i); //error in this line I get** 
        DashboardDto dashboardDto = mapToDto(obj, DashboardDto.class, false);

        result.add((DashboardDto) dashboardDto);    
    }

    for (Dashboard obj : dashboard){
        **DashboardDto dashboardDto = mapToDto(obj, DashboardDto.class, false);// error in this line I get**
        result.add((DashboardDto) dashboardDto);
    }*/

    Iterator itr = dashboard.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        **Dashboard obj = (Dashboard) itr.next(); // error here itself**

    }

    return result;
```

Lines in double * are the ones where error pops up for each of the loop.. Please give suggestions

[Image contains the resultset which is a list of entity class object but  i am not able to type cast to enitity Class itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0XPj.jpg)

While retrieving data from DB i am returning list of entity class but instead of list of entity class I am getting list of java object.. so I assume may be some configuration or something is missing..

for me its a custom query 
@Query(value = "SELECT sol.offering, sol.state ,COUNT(sol.id) FROM Solution sol GROUP BY sol.offering,sol.state")
    public List findAll();

Comment: There are numerous very similar questions on SO, all pointing to the same cause (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280818/java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-entity-usere ) did you have a look at those?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: \[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to entity.UserEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280818/java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-entity-usere)

Comment: The answer is in your screenshot. 
Your repository doesn't return a `List<Dashboard>`. It returns a `List<Object[]>`.
In your debugger, you can deploy `elementData[0]` to check what is exactly inside each `Object[]`. Therefore, previous comment are right, and you should now understand the answer of the linked question.

Comment: Nope, you are not using the JPA API. You are using "Spring Data JPA". As the person who has chosen to use that technology you *ought* to know the difference

Comment: I have tried the solution provided in other similar links even those solution throw exactly the same solution

Answer (score 1):

list() method return `List`, you can not directly cast them like you have done.

```
List<Dashboard> dashboard = (List<Dashboard>)dashboardRepository.findAll();
```

you have to store in `List<Object[]>` and iterate `List<Object[]>` one by one then convert into `List<Dashboard>`.

```
List<Object[]> list= (List<Object[]>)dashboardRepository.findAll();
List<Dashboard> mylist=new ArrayList<>();

            if(list!=null){
            for(Object [] ob:list){
                member1=ob[0];
                member2=ob[1];
                .......
                Dashboard db=new Dashboard(menber1,member2...);//or you use setter method for class member initialize.
                mylist.add(db);
            }
        }
```

Comment: first line itself.. it say cannot typcast dashboard to object list